# Need to reset an autosave timer when the document is saved manually

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have some code autosaving my Excel project. I am looking for a way to stop / reset the autosave timer when the document is saved manually. This is what I am using for the autosave.

```
If ThisWorkbook.Name = "mydoc.xlsm" Then
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "Save_Workbook"
End If
```

I tried an if statement:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Saved = False Then
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "ShowMsg"
End If
```

To see if by saving the document I would stop ShowMsg from going off. But even after saving the document, ShowMsg goes off at the 1 minute mark. It doesn't change the timer.

## Edit: Solution I used

I was able to accomplish what I wanted using the following methods.

#### In the Workbook

I used the function Workbook_BeforeSave() in order to stop the timer after being saved.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUi As Boolean, _
    Cancel As Boolean)

    Call StopTimer

End Sub
```

This is calling the Module StopTimer(). Which is defined on the Module level.

```
Option Explicit
Public RunWhen
Public cRunWhat

Public Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    cRunWhat = "Save"
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
End Sub
Public Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=False
    StartTimer
End Sub
```

Now, I had a different function in the workbook calling StartTimer, and Save() was just a basic save the workbook function.

A main issue I was having was solved in another post, by me. [Linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774356/stoptimer-not-working-need-a-way-to-restart-my-timer-in-excel)

I will be copying this solution to that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `BeforeSave` event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave

Something like:

**In ThisWorkbook:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ 
        Cancel as Boolean) 
Call Timer
End Sub
```

**In Module:**

```
Sub Timer()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "Hello"
End Sub
Sub Hello()
MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use the `MsgBox` Prompt, otherwise I think this will trigger if they hit save, but don't actually save.

Comment: How do you run that event though? I did find that before posting, but couldn't seem to make it work in my project.

Comment: Are you placing it in "ThisWorkbook"?

Comment: I tried that as well as putting it in it's own module.

Comment: What I have above worked for me, I'm not 100% it would restart the timer though, it may start another timer. How do you have this code repeating?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't reset the timer, it just starts another timer.

Comment: Sounds like the timer needs to be in a variable, check out TIMER variable perhaps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function