# StopTimer() Not working. Need a way to restart my timer in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I asked a similar question yesterday, and I got an answer but now I am having a different problem with the solution that I found.

I have some excel code, and I have it setup to autosave. And it is setup to autosave on a timer. I want to be able to have that timer reset whenever I manually save the project, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am using the Workbook_BeforeSave command to do something (ideally reset the timer) before saving. That way if I manually save the workbook, it will start that timer over again.

I tried something like this:

Workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
    Cancel As Boolean)

Call StopTimer

End Sub
```

Module:

```
Public Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    cRunWhat = "AutoSave"
   Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
End Sub
Public Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

But that does not seem to work. I even tried a simplified version, where I start a timer, and then just manually run StopTimer, and it doesn't stop the timer.

Is there something that I am missing on how StopTimer() should be working?

Thanks for any help!

## Edit: Solution I used

I was able to accomplish what I wanted using the following methods.

#### In the Workbook

I used the function Workbook_BeforeSave() in order to stop the timer after being saved.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUi As Boolean, _
    Cancel As Boolean)

    Call StopTimer

End Sub
```

This is calling the Module StopTimer(). Which is defined on the Module level.

```
Option Explicit
Public RunWhen
Public cRunWhat

Public Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    cRunWhat = "Save"
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
End Sub
Public Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=False
    StartTimer
End Sub
```

Now, I had a different function in the workbook calling StartTimer, and Save() was just a basic save the workbook function.

The main issue I was having was solved here. But the other post I made helped me through it a little bit as well. [Linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760546/need-to-reset-an-autosave-timer-when-the-document-is-saved-manually)

The solution is copied here.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use the built-in AutoSave option?

Comment: I have the autosave timer triggering on a certain event inside the workbook.

Comment: 1) Are you using `Option Explicit` at the top of your module?  2) Are `cRunWhat` and `RunWhen` both module-level Public Variables?

Comment: I am not using Option Explicit at the top of my module and they were not public variables. I will try that now. Edit: I tried both, but it didn't change. Still can't stop the timer once started.

Comment: @Chronocidal I had an issue in a different place in my code. That did actually work. I can cancel the timer now. Thank you. If you want to post an answer I can mark that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, check that your Module starts with the magic line `Option Explicit` - this means that Excel will throw an error if you haven't *explicitly* defined a Variable before trying to use it.  Otherwise, it will treat it as a blank value by default.  There is actually a tickbox under Tools / Options ("Require Variable Declaration") to automatically shove this at the top of all your modules.

Without:

```
Sub BadCode()
    MsgBox 10 + NotAVariable
End Sub
```

> 10

With:

```
Option Explicit
Sub BadCode()
    MsgBox 10 + NotAVariable
End Sub
```

> Compile Error:
>   Variable not defined

---

Next, make sure that your Variables are defined at a *module* level, not in a `Sub` or `Function` - this means that *other* `Sub`s and `Function`s can "see" the variable:

Without:

```
Sub Part1()
    Dim SomeNumber AS Long
    SomeNumber = 4
End Sub

Sub PartB()
    MsgBox 10 + SomeNumber
End Sub
```

> Compile Error:
>   Variable not defined

With:

```
Dim SomeNumber AS Long

Sub Part1()
    SomeNumber = 4
End Sub

Sub PartB()
    MsgBox 10 + SomeNumber
End Sub
```

> 14

You can use `Dim SomeNumber`, `Public SomeNumber` or `Private SomeNumber` - using `Public` will let other **modules** "see" the variable too, while `Private` will only let code in that specific module "see" it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I was saving after the end of every line- but wanted to reset the autosave timer to x seconds in the future when I am editing multiple lines.

The Marco reports !Save function not available. Substituted with one of my SaveasXLSB Macros and it worked.

I am hoping this keeps kicking the can down the road so to speak so when the system is idle for that amount of time /then/ it saves...

```
Option Explicit
Public RunWhen
Public cRunWhat

Public Sub StartTimer(Optional StrTimevalue As String = "00:00:10")
    RunWhen = Now + TimeValue(StrTimevalue)
    cRunWhat = "SaveAsDefaultXLSB"
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
End Sub
Public Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=False
    StartTimer ""
End Sub
```